# Spring-ws Endpoint when xml element is ambiguous

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, endpoint

When creating an endpoint with spring web services, is it possible to have multiple endpoints for multiple xml requests that have the same root element using the @PayloadRoot annotation, is there a way to use XPath to refine the choice made by spring when requests are ambiguous in root element, or can I intercept the message to make my own decision?